# Load Shared Preferences in List View

Tags: java, android, listview

I've a problem with my app, i want load all datas stored in shared preferences, to show them in a list view. 
I Save names, i want show all names in list view.

Code :

//Save names in shared preferences

```
          SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Noms", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("nom", var);
                editor.commit();
```

//Show in list view

```
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Noms", 0);
    //String var = settings.getString("bbb", "null");

    Map<String,?> keys = settings.getAll();
    final String []names=new String[]{};
    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){

        //Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());

        String d =entry.getValue().toString();


    }
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Where is your adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your values into a List of strings and then:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

something like this:

```
Map<String,?> keys = settings.getAll();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    values.add(entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Comment: I know for the adapter thanks :)  but how I can add all my name in the array list to add it in List view ? :)

Comment: Yes it's work, But it replaces each new value, whenever I save an old one is deleted :( I think it comes from the key (in Shared preferences editor) when backing up which is always the same, how can I replace that?

Comment: I've find a solution : add a number after name of key and increment it ! It's work very great !! Thank for your help my friend :)